# Fail sending mail with Django

Tags: python, django, email, django-settings

I tried to send email using `django.core.mail` and I got the error:

```
Request Method: POST

Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/

Django Version: 1.11.10

Exception Type: gaierror

Exception Value:    

[Errno -2] Name or service not known

Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py in create_connection,
line 557

Python
Executable: /home/lucas/Documentos/projetos/advogados/venv/bin/python

Python Version: 2.7.12
```

After that I tried to send email using just python script like this and worked fine:

```
import smtplib    
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
server.starttls()  
server.login("my@email.com", "mypassword")    
msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"  
server.sendmail("my@email.com", "to@email.com", msg) 
server.quit()
```

So I created my own Email sender to use with Django:

```
import smtplib 
from django.conf import settings


def send_custom_mail(msg, to, subject):
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
    server = smtplib.SMTP(settings.EMAIL_HOST, settings.EMAIL_PORT)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to, message)
    server.quit()
```

And it is still not working and I receive the same error.

So I removed the settings vars and used the real values, and it WORKS!!!

I realize that the problem was related with settings vars, and I logged them and theyre type, string for host, pass and user and int for port. OK !

I don't know how to check or fix that, other vars like ALLOWED_HOSTS and SECRET_KEY are working fine

I'm using decouple lib to remove sensitive data from settings

Comment: Can you please update your question with related `settings.py` as well?

Comment: Try this: `server = smtplib.SMTP()`
and connect like this:  `server.connect(settings.EMAIL_HOST, settings.EMAIL_PORT)`

Comment: You haven't shown how you are using `python-decouple`, so we can't tell what the problem might be.